# How do I use an integer type of a specific size in C++?

Tags: c++, types, integer

I need integer types of specific widths in C++, but I am not sure what type to use: `int`, `long`, etc. I realize I could use `sizeof` to find the size of each different integer type, but `int`, `long` and `long long` are not platform independent. This task would also be way too tedious.

Is there any way to specifiy an integer type of a specific size (such as a 32-bit or 64-bit integer) in C++? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: can you provide an example of how you would use it?

Comment: where do you read the bytes from? Why don't you know the size? Because you always have to know the layout. Even serialization formats need to define the length of each field some how

Comment: types are usually determined at compile time. You can select a type at runtime, but it is rather limited what you can do with it at runtime. For dynamic size you can consider a `std::vector<std::byte>`

Comment: @phuclv I know the number of bytes to read, but I didn't know how to select a type. However, Ryan Zhang helped me

Comment: When reading unknown data from a file, the data could also be part of a struct or a UTF string.

Comment: I don't think the word "dynamically" belongs in this question.

Answer (score 7):

I think what you're looking for is [fixed width integer types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer). These are defined in the header `<cstdint>`.

For your purposes, you could stick with `int[xx]_t`, where you replace `[xx]` with the width of the integer type you need, in bits. `uint[xx]_t` does something similar, with unsigned integer types.

You could, for example, use `int8_t`, `int16_t`, `uint8_t`, `uint_16t`, etc.

Comment: This was what I was looking for. I have wondered this for years. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to work out the type at compile time from a constexpr number of bits you can do:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template <int NumBits, typename=void>
struct uint_selector;

template <int NumBits>
struct uint_selector<NumBits, std::enable_if_t< 0 <= NumBits && NumBits <= 8>>
{
    typedef uint8_t int_type;
};

template <int NumBits>
struct uint_selector<NumBits, std::enable_if_t<8 < NumBits && NumBits <= 16 >>
{
    typedef uint16_t int_type;
};

template <int NumBits>
struct uint_selector<NumBits, std::enable_if_t<16 < NumBits && NumBits <= 32 >>
{
    typedef uint32_t int_type;
};

template <int NumBits>
struct uint_selector<NumBits, std::enable_if_t<32 < NumBits && NumBits <= 64 >>
{
    typedef uint64_t int_type;
};

// Then use as:
int main()
{
    // my_val will be the smallest standard type which is big enough type to hold 15 bits (e.g. a uint16_t)
    uint_selector<15>::int_type my_val = 5;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I used a pattern very similar to this myself recently. The `std::enable_if_t` trick is a neat thing you're using that I didn't though, nice! I would use `std::size_t` for `NumBits` personally as it feels a more natural type for specifying such property and it can't be negative.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `template` specialization of a type trait, provided you know the sizes at compile time.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <type_traits>

template <std::size_t SIZE>
struct num_selector;

template<>
struct num_selector<sizeof(short)> {
    using type = short;
};

template<>
struct num_selector<sizeof(int)> {
    using type = int;
};

template <std::size_t SIZE>
using num_selector_t = typename num_selector<SIZE>::type;

int main() {
    std::uint8_t shortish[sizeof(short)];
    std::uint8_t intish[sizeof(int)];

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<num_selector_t<sizeof(shortish)>, short>);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<num_selector_t<sizeof(intish)>, int>);
    return 0;
}
```

This make some assumptions that `short` and `int` are different sizes, but that's reasonable on most platforms (and can be checked via `static_assert` if you're concerned).

If you don't know how many bytes you're going to read until you're actually reading them (e.g., some end of field marker), you're better off picking the largest type you could ever need and just dealing with that.